# Is it true you shouldn't update your global python verision of python on mac?

Tags: python, macos, global

I know this question been answered else where on Stack, but the many of the questions are from years ago. Just wondering has this changed? I have Mac Catalina v10.15.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updating system python can be tricky because some system installed apps may rely on the binary at that prefix.

If you want to install another version of python, just use `miniconda`. It is extremely easy to set up from command line and you can then use multiple environments without disturbing the system.

Comment: see also: asdf, tox, poetry, virtualenv